# Moodle validation not working

Tags: php, moodle

I need a custom validation on submit, I did the coding as below:

```
<?php

require_once("{$CFG->libdir}/formslib.php");

class pool_status_form extends moodleform {

   function definition() {
global $DB, $USER, $qnsCount;

       $mform =&$this->_form;
//number of question per user
$mform->addElement('text', 'peruser', get_string('peruserquestion', 'qpool'), array('id' => 'peerqn'));
$mform->addRule('peruser', null, 'required', null, 'client');
$mform->addRule('peruser', null, 'numeric', null, 'client');
$mform->setType('peruser', PARAM_RAW);


//$this->add_action_buttons(false, 'SAVE');
$mform->addElement('submit', 'subbtn', get_string("buttonlabel", "qpool"));

   }


public function validation($data, $files) {


$errors = parent::validation($data, $files);

if (($data['peruser'])>3) {

$errors['peruser'] = "Error..";

}

return $errors;
}
}
```

When I click submit button it is directly submitting, it is not checking the validations I have mentioned inside my

'function validation'. What should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'validation' function runs on the server. Just call $form->get_data() and it will trigger.

Also, why are you adding the 'required' rule twice?
Why is the data type PARAM_RAW - it looks like PARAM_INT to me.